# Values cannot be returned until Resolution is frozen (Upgrade Umbraco version 4.9.1 to 4.11.1)

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco, upgrade

When I upgraded umbraco V4.9.1 to V4.11.1, in last step I have encountered a problem.
I just overwrite the /bin, /install, /umbraco and /umbraco_client folder and run it.
Problem was "Values cannot be returned until Resolution is frozen".

PLEASE HELP ME.

[image]

Comment: This should help http://our.umbraco.org/forum/core/general/35402-Values-cannot-be-returned-until-Resolution-is-frozen

Comment: I found the solution.I checkout all files project and disconnected from TFS. Then I used "Manage NuGet Packages" and I install Umbraco from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Dave linked, the actual root of the issue comes from Global.asax.cs not inheriting from the Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication class.

I know this is an old post, but it is unanswered and the resolution at this point (a comment) does not solve the issue for everybody as it is not even an option for many upgrading users as the route mentioned will overwrite ones global.asax . -Just want to give quick mark for posterity so this question is answered with a universal resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Try out the following Steps.,

1. delete global.asax from server
2. refresh site
3. copy again global.asax on server

Answer (score 1):

`enter code here`if You have Global.asax file like following

```
<%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication" Language="C#" %>
```

[image]

delete your Global.asax and add global application class

[image]

then in your code behind, change System.Web.HttpApplication to UmbracoApplication

```
 public partial class Global : UmbracoApplication
    {


    }
```